# How to dynamically detect user is standing or sitting mode in Kinect SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, xbox360

I am developing a gesture based C# application which will predict the gesture with the help of kinect Device (SDK 2.0) . I can do the gesture detection when user is in standing but not working in sitting position . I want to work my gestures in both sitting and standing position . I can get 20 Skeleton in standing with tracked . How can i know whether is user is standing or sitting when i plug kinect device  ?

```
 Kinect_sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
 BodyFrameReader bodyFrameReader = Kinect_sensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();
 bodyFrameReader.FrameArrived += Kinect__SkeletonFrameReady;
 Kinect_sensor.Open();
```

Is there any way to predict the user is in standing / sitting position ?

Comment: Are you looking for ***Discrete Gesture Basics Sample*** of Kinect SDk Browser who display if user as Seated or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking the positions of bones relative to one another?

If the hips are above the knees by some threshold maybe the user is standing.

You might also just be able to check how far the hips (or some other bone) is above the ground plane.

Comment: I done that by checking the distance between shoulder and knee . That is working like when i stand , the distance is increasing . While sitting mode , the distance will decrease . Thanks for the valuable reply .

Answer (score -1):

I done with checking the distance between shoulder and knee .